# How to add spinner after 500ms pending AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have a trivial problem that I'm eager to solve correctly, with jQuery 3. So the idea is this:

1. Do AJAX request
2. Await response. If there is no response after 500ms, show spinner
3. Hide spinner when we've got a response.

I currently I have something working. But the question is: Is this the correct or preferred way of doing it?

```
// helper function for setTimeout
function wait(ms) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() { deferred.resolve() }, ms);
    return deferred.promise();
}

var request = $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/api/articles/?" + $.param(params)
});

wait(500).then(function() {
    if (request.state() === "pending") // works, but the docs says we should do this only for debugging purposes
        $(".spinner").show();
});

request.always(function() {
    $(".spinner").hide();
);
```

Can we use `request.state()` this way? Could this have been solved in a more elegant way?

Comment: `var deferred = $.Defereed();` should probably be `var deferred = $.Deferred();`.

Comment: Try and look at this, What you need should be right at the top https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: I would suggest using a CSS animation with an `animation-delay: 500;`. Apply the class that has the animated spinner right when you fire the AJAX request, remove the class from the element on response.

Comment: What I would do is to save a reference to the timer in the global scope, so I can check it and cancel if appropiate. Something like `var timer; /* global scope */` and then `timer = setTimeout(...);`. The funcion that `setTimeout()` calls would be `function showTimer() { $(".spinner").show() }` and when the AJAX is done, cancel the timer: `timer.clearTimeout();` and clear the loading indicator (`$(".spinner").hide();`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really try to do things like this without synchronous inspection of promise state.

Fairly minor modifications to the code are required.

- return a *Deferred* from `wait()` instead of a promise.
- call `wait(500)` and keep a reference to the returned Deferred.
- show the spinner unconditionally on fulfillemnt of the `wait(500)` Deferred.
- reject the `wait(500)` Deferred on settlement of the ajax promise, thereby ensuring that the timeout can't resolve it later.

This will effectively set up a race between the `wait(500)` deferred and the `$.ajax()` promise, the former trying to display the spinner and the latter trying to prevent it.

```
function delay(ms) {
    return jQuery.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
        setTimeout(dfrd.resolve, ms);
    });
}

var showSpinner = delay(500); // a Deferred that will be resolved after 500ms, unless rejected before that.

showSpinner.then(function() {
    $(".spinner").show();
}, function() {
    console.log('The ajax request settled before the timeout');
});

jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/api/articles/?' + $.param(params)
}).always(function() {
    $(".spinner").hide(); // hide spinner (if the timeout won the race)
    showSpinner.reject(); // prevent the spinner from being shown
});
```